# Есть ли в русском языке какой-то фразеологизм, обозначающий удачу сразу во всем?

Tags: фразеология, идиомы

Например, человек делал ставку и угадал исход сразу всех событий.

Попал в яблочко здесь не совсем то, ибо нужно подчеркнуть, что человек смог точно угадать сразу несколько вещей.

Comment: Готового фразеологизма нет. Если нужно в двух словах сказать метафорой, то можно так "повезло в квадрате"/Повезло сразу во всех ставках/итп

Comment: Рождённый в рубашке... Это о даре "поцелованного Богом" преодолевать непреодолимое играючи.

Comment: "быть на коне", само по себе оно не совсем про удачу, но по смыслу близко: "он сегодня на коне"

Answer (score 0):

Для таких случаев подойдёт выражение: "(получить) всё и сразу". Вы просмотрели его, когда задавали свой вопрос. Также "убить сразу двух (пять, семь и т.д.) зайцев", "одним махом семерых убивахом"
В отечественном сквернословии есть поговорка: "Что, хочешь и на х** сесть, и рыбку съесть?"

Answer (score 0):

Да, такой фразеологизм есть. Он просторечный, но не жаргонный: "пошлà пруха"

Пример употребления:

- "Сел я с ними в карты, и тут пошла такая пруха."

Более жаргонные обороты используют глагол "фартить", который особенно популярен в уголовной среде.

Пример употребления:

- "Денёк был на славу, фартило во всём."